# Incorrect filename after saving file with duplicate name (Android 8.1)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating file on my device using method from Google docs:

```
private val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()) { uri ->
        uri?.let { writeToFile(requireActivity(), it) }
    }
```

then launch it:

```
getContent.launch("file.csv")
```

When i'm creating file with same name it's saving as "file.csv(1)" in my file explorer but "file(1).csv" expected (even in Google docs). So i can't open it because file have .csv(1) not .csv format.

On Emulator with Android 11 it's ok. Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: There is nothing really for you to solve. If the user chooses a name that exists, the documents provider will substitute some alternative name. How it does that is up to the documents provider. Not only can that vary by OS version but also by the documents provider itself (filesystem vs. Google Drive vs. others).

Comment: @CommonsWare it's strange. When it's like ".csv(1)" i can't even open it. I should rename it which is annoying to be honest.